# Creep on a load cell

Tags: load-cell, transducer

I am working with a 50kg load cell. In the datasheet(https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/loadsensor.pdf), the creep is defined by (3min)%FS. What does it mean?

Comment: It means the creep, (the amount the reading changes) measured over 3 minutes, will be within that value. You're probably better finding out the components Sparkfun are selling, and going to the original source's datasheet.

Comment: I dont think I got it. Does the information help me to "predict" the change?

Comment: No, it allows you to predict upper and lower bounds on the change.

Comment: No. The datasheet doesn't tell you the exact amount it will change (creep). It could be zero, or it could be +/- 0.3% of fullscale reading after three minutes.

Comment: Similar to this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106143/does-this-loadcells-creep-mean-that-i-can-not-let-a-constant-load-on-the-loadce?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa question

Answer (score 1):

The are all errors: offset (zero) and gain  errors relative to FS.

```
Nonlinearity %FS              0.03%
Repeatability %FS             0.03%
Hysteresis %FS                0.03%
Creep (3min)%FS               0.03%
Zero Drift (1min)%FS          0.03%
Temp. Effect on Zero %FS/10℃  1% or 0.1%/'C 3min
Temp. Effect on Output %FS/10℃ 0.05% or 0.05%/'C
```

It stretches ( creep ) under load but returns back with hysteresis and return creep. It is the error due to slight plasticity material properties, rather than pure elastic stiff spring of the load cell. After all the ideal strain gauge is a pure spring resistor bridge.

```
Total Gain error    0.12% FS + 0.05%/'C 
Total Offset error  0.03% FS + 0.1% FS/'C
```

Comment: "Another silent -1 afraid to voice their ignorance"
Sorry, I didn't get it

Comment: someone who thinks their opinion is worth something , but isn't, down-voted it -1 without comment or question.  This serves to notice them that I don't care but they ought to be ashamed